Show $\sum_{k=0}^{b-1} \left\lfloor \frac{ka}{b} \right\rfloor = \sum_{k=0}^{a-1} \left\lfloor \frac{kb}{a} \right\rfloor$ for positive integers a,b.
How can we show, that
$\sum_{k=0}^{b-1} \left\lfloor \frac{ka}{b} \right\rfloor = \sum_{k=0}^{a-1} \left\lfloor \frac{kb}{a} \right\rfloor$ for positive integers a and b? I tried to solve the problem for positive integers a and b such that gcd(a,b) = 1, but I could only show that $\sum_{k=0}^{b-1} \left\lfloor \frac{ka}{b} \right\rfloor = (b-1)(a-1) - \sum_{k=0}^{a-1} \left\lfloor \frac{kb}{a} \right\rfloor$. After experimenting a bit, It seems to me that $\sum_{k=0}^{a-1} \left\lfloor \frac{kb}{a} \right\rfloor = \frac{1}{2}(b-1)(a-1)$ with gcd(a,b) = 1, though I am not certain of this nor do I know how to prove such a claim. As this question is from a maths competition for high school students, I am looking for a rather elementary way of solving the problem.
Any insight into solving the general problem or the special case with coprime a and b would be much appreciated.
(Edit: A few have pointed out that this problem relates to Pick’s Theorem, but this connection seems unintuitive to me. Though this is what makes maths beautiful, I am hoping for a simpler solution)

Draw a right triangle, which $a, b$ are the two sides of it. You can put it on a lattice points, then count the inner points with two respective ways.

addition) that’s why you have something about $(a-1)(b-1).$

How do you come up with this? Or are you familiar with Pick’s Theorem? Sorry for the many questions, I am trying to understand your intuition. Either way, thanks for your answer.

Just by visualizing some trials to graph such as $(a, b) = (2, 3), (2, 5), (3, 5), \cdots$ you can see something like triangle, as you try bigger numbers. I got it by rotating one’s graph an could find some figure like triangle.

Maybe this graph may help you, just regard the lattice points of it.
